# Should I use an initialization vector (IV) along with my encryption?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Is it recommended that I use an [initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) to encrypt/decrypt my data? Will it make things more secure? Is it one of those things that need to be evaluated on a case by case basis?

To put this into actual context, the Win32 Cryptography function, [CryptSetKeyParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380272(VS.85).aspx) allows for the setting of an initialization vector on a key prior to encrypting/decrypting. Other API's also allow for this.

What is generally recommended and why?

Comment: This is a great question, IMHO.  But read all the answers and think for yourself (don't be intimidated by the "if you researched crypto you'd already know" ... there's a lot of silliness below)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An IV is essential when the same key might ever be used to encrypt more than one message.

The reason is because, under most encryption modes, two messages encrypted with the same key can be analyzed together.  In a simple stream cipher, for instance, XORing two ciphertexts encrypted with the same key results in the XOR of the two messages, from which the plaintext can be easily extracted using traditional cryptanalysis techniques.

A weak IV is part of what made WEP breakable.

An IV basically mixes some unique, non-secret data into the key to prevent the same key ever being used twice.

Answer (score 9):

In most cases you should use IV. Since IV is generated randomly each time, if you encrypt same data twice, encrypted messages are going to be different and it will be impossible for the observer to say if this two messages are the same.

Answer (score 5):

Take a good look at a picture (see below) of CBC mode.  You'll quickly realize that an attacker knowing the IV is like the attacker knowing a previous block of *ciphertext* (and yes they already know plenty of that).

Here's what I say: most of the "problems" with IV=0 are general problems with block encryption modes when you *don't* ensure data integrity.  You really must ensure integrity.

Here's what I do: use a strong checksum (cryptographic hash or HMAC) and prepend it to your plaintext before encrypting.  There's your known first block of ciphertext: it's the IV of the same thing without the checksum, and you need the checksum for a million other reasons.

Finally: any analogy between CBC and stream ciphers is not terribly insightful IMHO.

Just look at the picture of CBC mode, I think you'll be pleasantly surprised.

Here's a picture:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation

[link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation)

Comment: +1. Seems like a good idea, and I can't think of any holes in it, but I'd still caution people against inventing their own modes of operation.

Comment: Using an unencrypted hash or MAC of the plaintext is also not a good idea, as it allows seeing if two messages are equal. Don't do this.

Comment: Paulo, my answer doesn't suggest using an *unencrypted* MAC *as* the IV, rather that the first block of plaintext be the MAC.  Effectively then the "IV" becomes that MAC encrypted.  It's true then, if the entire sequence of CBC blocks is the same twice that the plaintext would be the same.  But, there are cases where two parties need to encrypt the same message w/o negotiating an IV in or out-of-band (say to prove to a 3rd party they both know a secret).  It would be up to the parent protocol to handle asynchronous encryption properly.  *Some* uses of symmetric encryption can be deterministic.

Answer (score 3):

If the same key is used multiple times for multiple different secrets patterns could emerge in the encrypted results. The IV, that should be pseudo random and used only once with each key, is there to obfuscate the result. You should never use the same IV with the same key twice, that would defeat the purpose of it.

To not have to bother keeping track of the IV the simplest thing is to prepend, or append it, to the resulting encrypted secret. That way you don't have to think much about it. You will then always know that the first or last N bits is the IV.

When decrypting the secret you just split out the IV, and then use it together with the key to decrypt the secret.

Answer (score 2):

I found the writeup of HTTP Digest Auth ([RFC 2617](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2617.html)) very helpful in understanding the use and need for IVs / nonces.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it one of those things that need to be evaluated on a case by case
>   basis?

Yes, it is. Always read up on the cipher you are using and how it expects its inputs to look. Some ciphers don't use IVs but do require salts to be secure. IVs can be of different lengths. The mode of the cipher can change what the IV is used for (if it is used at all) and, as a result, what properties it needs to be secure (random, unique, incremental?).

It is generally recommended because most people are used to using AES-256 or similar block ciphers in a mode called 'Cipher Block Chaining'. That's a good, sensible default go-to for a lot of engineering uses and it needs you to have an appropriate (non-repeating) IV. In that instance, it's not optional.

Answer (score 0):

The IV allows for plaintext to be encrypted such that the encrypted text is harder to decrypt for an attacker. Each bit of IV you use will double the possibilities of encrypted text from a given plain text.

For example, let's encrypt 'hello world' using an IV one character long. The IV is randomly selected to be 'x'. The text that is then encrypted is then 'xhello world', which yeilds, say, 'asdfghjkl'. If we encrypt it again, first generate a new IV--say we get 'b' this time--and encrypt like normal (thus encrypting 'bhello world'). This time we get 'qwertyuio'.

The point is that the attacker doesn't know what the IV is and therefore must compute every possible IV for a given plain text to find the matching cipher text. In this way, the IV acts like a [password salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_salt). Most commonly, an IV is used with a chaining cipher (either a stream or block cipher). In a chaining block cipher, the result of each block of plain text is fed to the cipher algorithm to find the cipher text for the next block. In this way, each block is chained together.

So, if you have a random IV used to encrypt the plain text, how do you decrypt it? Simple. Pass the IV (in plain text) along with your encrypted text. Using our fist example above, the final cipher text would be 'xasdfghjkl' (IV + cipher text).

Yes you should use an IV, but be sure to choose it properly. Use a good random number source to make it. Don't ever use the same IV twice. And **never** use a constant IV.

The Wikipedia article on [initialization vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) provides a general overview.

Comment: "The point is that the attacker doesn't know what the IV is and therefore must compute every possible IV for a given plain text"

The attacker _does_ know the IV - as you say later, you include the IV with the ciphertext.

Comment: Sorry, half of this answer is complete nonsense. It is tragic that such answers get lots of upvotes.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Answers like this (and the upvotes attached to it) make me wonder how familiar programmers really are with cryptography. It kind of worries me.

Comment: Perhaps some of you who are so eager to say what is wrong with the existing answers would care to provide the correct answer?