# Manipulating the Initialization Vector does not (really) prevent me from decrypting AES ciphertexts

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, initialization-vector

I created the following class, based from the examples on MSDN:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/19d9e5f6747dfe75d553

Whenever I use it like this, it seems like it encrypts fine:

```
var key = Crypto.GenerateKey();
var vector = Crypto.GenerateVector(key);

var cypherText = Crypto.EncryptBase64("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890", key, vector);
vector = Crypto.GenerateVector(key);
var plainText = Crypto.Decrypt(cypherText, key, vector);
```

Then `plainText` contains the following:

`�\aU��(���P\u0003�b\u001dxqrstuvwxyz1234567890`

So it seems changing the IV, doesn't really do anything (especially on longer documents). Why do we even need an IV?

Comment: Without IV, same `plainText` plus same `key` will produce same `cypherText`. Using different IVs allows us to produce different `cypherText` for same `plainText` plus same `key`. IV is not meant to be hidden from attacker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use an initialization vector (IV) along with my encryption?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65879/should-i-use-an-initialization-vector-iv-along-with-my-encryption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default mode of operation for `SymmetricAlgorithm` is `CipherMode.CBC`.

Given the way [how the CBC mode works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) the change of *IV* of encrypted data will impact only the first decrypted block of data.

Citing the linked article:

> Decrypting with the incorrect IV causes the first block of plaintext
>   to be corrupt but subsequent plaintext blocks will be correct. This is
>   because a plaintext block can be recovered from two adjacent blocks of
>   ciphertext. As a consequence, decryption can be parallelized. Note
>   that a one-bit change to the ciphertext causes complete corruption of
>   the corresponding block of plaintext, and inverts the corresponding
>   bit in the following block of plaintext, but the rest of the blocks
>   remain intact.

This is one of the reasons why encryption without authentication (e.g. [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33569/why-do-you-need-message-authentication-in-addition-to-encryption)) is not a good idea.

On the other hand changing the *IV* during the encryption results in a completely different ciphertext as the change in the first block is propagated to all the subsequent blocks.

Desclaimer: I am no crypto expert, so please do validate my thoughts.